# How do I trade with friends over the internet in Pokemon Sun/Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-seventh-generation

It might just be me, but I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to trade with a friend over the internet.

How do you trade in Pokemon Sun Moon? Is it as convoluted as I think it is?

Comment: Something went terribly wrong if you have to ask this question...

Comment: @pinckerman just confusing as hell the first time. Hopefully the below guide will help others.

Comment: I was wondering how to accomplish this with my friend just now and then I thought "Hey, Robotnik posted a tutorial the other day!" +1

Comment: @Vemonus - I'm helping! :-) (Also, wow almost at 18k views, Nintendo/Gamefreak take note: make your UIs less complicated!)

Comment: Yeah, in terms of wifi things, festival plaza is a HUGE downgrade from the PSS in gen 6. Classic game freak; one step forward, two steps back.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. **Configure an internet connection on your 3DS**

   - From the 3DS Main menu, Go to System Settings (Wrench icon) -> Internet Settings -> Connection Settings
   - Click 'New Connection' -> Manual Setup -> Search for Access Point
   - Click your Wifi name, and enter your password
   - Ensure the test connection succeeds.
2. **Add your Friend**

   - From the Main menu, click the 'Friend List' icon (the Orange Smiley face)
   - Give your friend your 'Friend Code', and ask for theirs
   - Click 'Register Friend' -> via Internet and enter their friend code
3. **Go to Festival Plaza in Sun/Moon**

   - Start Sun/Moon, load your game, then open the Menu
   - Open 'Festival Plaza' - by default it's on the second screen of options

     > Notes:
     >   *You will need to go through a short tutorial if you haven't opened it before*
     >   Festival Plaza will be enabled once you reach the first Pokémon Center in the game. If you don't see it, continue the story.
4. **Connect Sun/Moon to the internet**

   - On the bottom screen there will be a *"Connected to local wireless communication"* message.

     > **Ignore this.** *You are **not** connected to the internet at large and thus cannot trade with your online friend just yet.*
   - Click the 'Wifi' symbol in the bottom-right of the bottom screen.
   - Follow the prompts to connect to the internet
   - Once connected, the message will change to *"Connected to the Internet"*
5. **Finally, Trade**

   - On the bottom screen (still in Festival Plaza), click 'Trade'
   - Click 'Link Trade'
   - Assuming your friend is online, they will show up in the 'Guest List'.

     > If you want to interact with them more in the future, it is recommended you add them to your 'VIP List' to make them easier to find in the future. You can do this after the trade by going inside the castle and talking to your friend's character standing near one of the tables.
   - Click your friend's name and follow the prompts.

Comment: Can confirm after testing with Robotnik, the process really is that unintuitive.

Comment: what to do if your friend still doesnt show up on the guest list?

Comment: @user171959 Make sure they have done the same thing on their end...

Comment: Re "Connected to local wireless communication": I believe you will be able to trade/interact with friends and people who are physically near you and have the Festival Plaza open.

Comment: @Schism Correct (although using the Quick Link button in the main menu is faster than going through Festival Plaza for local trading).